# Dynamic variable name php 7.4 and value assigment

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, dynamic

I used to create dynamic variable and assign values to them like this

```
$total{$column} = 0;
```

and output it like this

```
echo $total{$column};
```

But in php 7.4 {} braces have depricated and we have to use [] braces instead. It is fine when we are dealing with array. but while creating dynamic variable name. It returns following error.

> Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in .....

short summary is. I want to create dynamic variable name and assign value like this

```
$totalA = 20;
$totalB = 10;
```

This method $total{$column} works fine in older php versions. But Unable to get same result in php 7.4.

Is there anyone to guide.

Thanks

Comment: Variable variables are bad. Use arrays and appropriate string keys instead. Format a key before using it, with `sprintf()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code will work in the newest version of PHP as well.

```
$column = 'A';

${"total{$column}"} = 20;

echo ${"total{$column}"}; // 20

echo $totalA; // 20
```

Comment: As of PHP8, this is indeed one of ways of working with variable variables (see [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php)).